# How to call data setState to in react render return?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, meteor, react-component

I can call data in `console.log(this.state.eventUser);` render return and its showing all of the data in eventUser. But when I try to call `console.log(this.state.eventUser._id);` its showing error of this `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of undefined`. How can I solve this issue?

```
    componentDidMount(){
        Tracker.autorun(() => {
            Meteor.subscribe('allUsers');
            const userId = this.props.location.state.event.userID;
            const eventUser = Meteor.users.findOne({_id: userId});
            this.setState({ eventUser });
        });
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                {console.log(this.state.eventUser._id)}
            </div>
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably at some point `this.state.eventUser` in the render is undefined.

Try this

```
{this.state.eventUser && console.log(this.state.eventUser._id)
```

Comment: This will not work as he is executing asynchronous code so this.setState call will always set the eventUser data to undefined. It can be solved by using a then function or async await as described in my example

Answer (score 0):

You can't use console.log inside JSX without enclosing in {} 
Try below code

```
render(){
    return(
        <div>
            {put javascript here}
        </div>
    );
}
```

**Edit:**

Your code is executing query on Database which is asynchronous
So you need to wait for it to complete.
Below is an implementation of async/await (es7+ features of javascript)

Try below code

```
 componentDidMount(){
            Tracker.autorun(async () => {
                Meteor.subscribe('allUsers');
                const userId = this.props.location.state.event.userID;
                const eventUser = await Meteor.users.findOne({_id: userId});
                this.setState({ eventUser });
            });
        }
```

Comment: sorry it's my writing mistake. I have changed the code. I have already tried with this. but not working.

Comment: try debugging by changing console.log to this
console.log(this.state)
and check if the desired data is present or not.

Comment: @VijaySingh I'm not sure if this will fix the problem, as eventUser will still be undefined when the render() function attempts to access it, causing the error in the original post.

Comment: You are right a check for undefined is still required

Answer (score 0):

It looks like by the time your `render()` function runs, the user hasn't yet be saved to the component state.

To fix this, add a constructor to your component in which you define the eventUser as an empty object.

```
class MyClass extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state {
      eventUser: {}
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    Tracker.autorun(() => {
        Meteor.subscribe('allUsers');
        const userId = this.props.location.state.event.userID;
        const eventUser = Meteor.users.findOne({_id: userId});
        this.setState({ eventUser });
    });
  }

  render(){
    console.log(this.state.eventUser._id)
    return(
      <div>My Test Page</div>
    );
  }
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: This doesnt solve full problem. The main issue here is that the Database query is asynchronous code. by the time this.setState is called the eventUser variable is still not done fetching data from database due to javascript eventloop

Comment: JavaScript throws a TypeError when it attempts to access a key of an undefined object. As long as the object is defined (even if it's an empty object),  the program will continue to run, and will re-render with the correct value after the data is fetched.

Comment: You are right about TypeError but if you look at componentdDidMount the setState will run only once and the database query will be resolved later and hence that issue can be solved by either implementing then function or async/await

Answer (score 0):

`componentDidMount` will fire after the component has already been mounted (as the name states). At the point where it reaches the enclosed statement the state has not been set yet.

I'm not sure why you are using a console.log inside of your render return, but if you are looking to actually display the user ID, conditional rendering is your friend: `{this.state.eventUser && this.state.eventUser._id}`

Answer (score 0):

For the first time when your component will render, if you have knowledge about react lifecycle hooks, after constructor the `render method` will be triggered then `componentDidMount` hook.
so for the first render the `eventUser` is undefined then after `componentDidMount` the state will be fulfilled.

So solution is:

- First don't put `console.log` in JSX, it is better to put it before `return`.
- Second first check if the object is defined then return your data

**Code:**

```
render(){
       const { eventUser } = this.state;

        // if eventUser is defined then log it
        {eventUser && console.log(eventUser._id)}

        // or you can add very simple load state
       if(!eventUser) return <h1>Loading....</h1>

    return(
        <div>
            {probably info about user }
        </div>
    );
}
```